# distinct in query repeating values

Tags: mysql, distinct

I wonder if anyone can spot the problem with this 'view' query to show only 'company' and 'materials'.  The problem is that it shows each entry a separate time for each material and company.  I'm using this view to populate a dropdown box in a form but I would only like it to show the distinct values for each column (company/materials) - as of now if, for example, end result is the company 'Anderson' twice but with different materials for each...it shows 'Anderson' twice.  I've tried using DISTINCT after the select statement for each of the two, but I don't achieve what I want.

```
select `b`.`company` AS `company`, `bp`.`material` AS `material` 
from (((`caseys_wrdp4`.`windows_brands_products` `bp` 
        left join `caseys_wrdp4`.`windows_brands` `b` on((`bp`.`brand_id` = `b`.`id`))) 
       join `caseys_wrdp4`.`Windows_last_submissions` `ls`) 
      join `caseys_wrdp4`.`windows_materials` `wm`) 
where ((`bp`.`width` = round(`ls`.`width`,0)) 
       and (`bp`.`height` = round(`ls`.`height`,0))
       and (`bp`.`material` = `wm`.`name`) 
       and (`bp`.`type` = `ls`.`type`) 
       and if ((`ls`.`minimumbid` <> '0.00'),
               (`bp`.`cost` between `ls`.`minimumbid` and `ls`.`maximumbid`),
               (`bp`.`cost` <= `ls`.`maximumbid`)))
```

Comment: To be clear, are you trying to get an individual row for each company, with a field that has the list of materials?

Comment: `DISTINCT` applies to the combination, not each individual column. If it only shows `Anderson` once, which material should it show?

Comment: Maybe you want `GROUP_CONCAT(bp.material)` to list all the materials by company?

Comment: It looks like the problem is that you legitimately have multiple joining rows.  If the company "Anderson" has material "wood" and material "steel" then it's correctly showing you two rows. "Anderson, Wood" and "Anderson, Steel" are distinct.  You might want to try pulling your company first and then updating a material OR joining your materials into a single comma-separated string OR have the material pull back TOP 1 so it can only match 1 row.

Comment: Please post some sample data and the result you're trying to get. It's hard to figure out what you're asking for.

Comment: Kalimino, that is exactly what I'm speaking of.  haha, but could you please clarify which steps you believe could benefit me?  I very much want to learn but I'm pretty new with 'Views' as in how they look when I 'edit view' within phpmyadmin.  I know this is the right track though.

Comment: So basically the results from the view come from user search parameters that can possibly have multiple results.  So a parameter could be 'Wood' AND 'Vinyl' (the user chooses a range of prices to determine which 'company' will be given)...giving the 'Anderson' company but with 'Wood' and 'Vinyl' as a dropdown choice.   My situation is that 'Anderson' shows twice - which I do not want.

Answer (score 0):

Possible answer:

Add `GROUP_CONCAT` and `GROUP BY` to your query:

```
select `b`.`company` AS `company`, GROUP_CONCAT(`bp`.`material`) AS `materials` 
from (((`caseys_wrdp4`.`windows_brands_products` `bp` 
    left join `caseys_wrdp4`.`windows_brands` `b` on((`bp`.`brand_id` = `b`.`id`))) 
  join `caseys_wrdp4`.`Windows_last_submissions` `ls`) 
  join `caseys_wrdp4`.`windows_materials` `wm`) 
where ((`bp`.`width` = round(`ls`.`width`,0)) 
   and (`bp`.`height` = round(`ls`.`height`,0))
   and (`bp`.`material` = `wm`.`name`) 
   and (`bp`.`type` = `ls`.`type`) 
   and if ((`ls`.`minimumbid` <> '0.00'),
           (`bp`.`cost` between `ls`.`minimumbid` and `ls`.`maximumbid`),
           (`bp`.`cost` <= `ls`.`maximumbid`)))
GROUP BY(`b`.`company`);
```

This will give you back a single row for each company w/ `company` and `materials`. `materials` will be a comma-separated list (@Barmar). You could then parse that field for the 2nd drop down.

Example Rows:

`'Anderson'` `'Wood,Vinyl'`

`'WM'` `'Metal','Plastic'`

Assuming you're building a webpage, depending on how you're building the `DOM`, you can either use `javascript` `str.split()`, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split, or on the server side, any language should work.

Comment: It works exactly as desired..unfortunately I'm using a wordpress plugin to populate the dropdown and I'm not sure how to include JS to the form.  Question for you...why doesn't adding DISTINCT to the 'materials' show only a distinct value for each material?

Comment: As @Barmar said, `DISTINCT` gives you the distinct combination. Meaning, the combination of `Anderson` and `Wood` is `DISTINCT` from `Anderson` and `Steel`. If you had two rows that gave you `Anderson` and  `Wood`, `DISTINCT` would make that into one.

Comment: @CaseyStack Does this answer your question?